# multiple output and losses for multi-class image segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I use Keras with Tensorflow for a multi-class image segmentation problem. For each training pair `{(x_i,y_i)}^N`, my model has different auxiliary losses (`out_aux`) that are added together with one main (`out_main`) loss function.

```
                      Input(256,256,5)
                              |
                              |
                    something happening here

         /          |           |           |          \
        |           |           |           |           |
      out_main  out_aux(0)  out_aux(1)  out_aux(2)  out_aux(3)
```

At the moment, I'm using the same loss for all outputs ( `categorical_crossentropy`), so basically, a single (x,y)-pair is evaluated on all losses.  I'm having some issues when defining the model. The method to create the auxiliary losses looks as follows:

```
def aux_branch(self, x, nb_labels=5):
    # x is a list of feature maps.
    x_aux = []
    for nf in range(len(x)):
        x_in = x[nf]
        out_aux = _conv(filters=nb_labels, kernel_size=(1, 1), activation='linear')(x_in)
        out_aux = Reshape((im_rows * im_cols, nb_labels))(out_aux)
        out_aux = Activation('softmax')(out_aux)
        out_aux = Reshape((im_rows, im_cols, nb_labels), name='out_aux_{}'.format(nf))(out_aux)

        x_aux.append(out_aux)

    return x_aux
```

and the method to create and compile the model is defined as:

```
def create_model(self, x, lossfunc, nb_labels=5):
    ...
    ... 

    out_aux = self.aux_branch(x)
    ...
    out_main = _conv(filters=nb_labels, kernel_size=(1, 1), activation='linear')(out_main)
    out_main = Reshape((im_rows * im_cols, nb_labels))(out_main)
    out_main = Activation('softmax')(out_main)
    out_main = Reshape((im_rows, im_cols, nb_labels), name='out_main')(out_main)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[out_main, out_aux[0], out_aux[1], out_aux[2], out_aux[3], out_aux[4]])


    model.compile(loss={'out_aux_0': lossfunc,
                        'out_aux_1': lossfunc,
                        'out_aux_2': lossfunc,
                        'out_aux_3': lossfunc,
                        'out_aux_4': lossfunc,
                        'out_main': lossfunc},
                  # loss_weights={'out_aux_0': 1.0,
                  #               'out_aux_1': 1.0,
                  #               'out_aux_2': 1.0,
                  #               'out_aux_3': 1.0,
                  #               'out_aux_4': 1.0,
                  #               'out_main': 1.0},
                    optimizer=optimizer,
                    metrics={'out_main': 'accuracy',
                           'out_aux_0': 'accuracy',
                           'out_aux_1': 'accuracy',
                           'out_aux_2': 'accuracy',
                           'out_aux_3': 'accuracy',
                           'out_aux_4': 'accuracy'})

    ...
    results = model.fit_generator(
        generator=train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
        epochs=args.epochs,
        callbacks=callbacks,
        validation_data=val_generator,
        #nb_val_samples = nb_val_samples,
        validation_steps=validation_steps,
        #class_weight=class_weight
        initial_epoch=epoch_num+1
       )
```

As for the loss function, I'm using a standard categorical_crossentropy function from keras.
The error message that I get is:

```
File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 101, in standardize_input_data
str(len(data)) + ' arrays: ' + str(data)[:200] + '...')
ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 6 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[[[1., 0.],
     [1., 0.],
     [1., 0.],
     ...,
     [0., 1.],
     [0., 1.],
     [0., 1.]],

    [[1., 0.],
     [1., 0.],
     [1., 0.],
     ......
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post source code where error occurred?

Comment: @kvorobiev, I edited the post. the error occurred when calling the "fit_generator" method

Comment: And what contains (or how defined) `train_generator` at this moment?

Comment: @kvorobiev very similar to this: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3338#issuecomment-238485505 basically a pair of (image,mask)

Comment: @kvorobiev do i need to have instead of a pair (x,y) something like: (x,y,y,y,y,y) based on the number of loss functions?

Comment: From error message I think problem caused by wrong shape of `y` from `train_generator`. And to answer more precise I need to see defination of `train_generator`.

Comment: Try `train_generator = x+y+y+y+y+y`

Comment: @kvorobiev, it worked, thank you. Now, I've the problem that the model is not training and the accuracy remains at 50.00% when using all the losses. If I change the model, and use one single loss and any of them, then the model starts training accurately. Do you've any idea where the problem could be?